# How to develop a global Mutation class to perform an ADD Operation in Graphene-Django using GraphQL?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

Can anyone share how to develop a global Mutation class to perform an ADD Operation in Graphene-Django using GraphQL? I can write separate Mutations for individual Models but I want to use the main Mutation Class and want to reuse that passing my individual Model Names and their Properties/Attributes.

There are many models that just require basic ADD/update/delete mutations no other permutations or calculations are required.